# Deleting sql snapshots in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, snapshot

I have two different scripts, one created by me and one by my collegue, that is using the same snapshots.

16.00 (or 4 PM) Coded by me.
Script 1 - deletes snapshots if they are there, creates new snapshots - executes code.

04.00 (or 4 AM) Coded by Collegue
Script 2 - deletes snapshots if they are there, creates new snapshots - executes code.

Both of these scripts are SSIS scripts that are just holders for Stored Procedures (the SSIS scripts actually don't do much more than executes a bunch of Stored Procedures in a chain).

Script 2 works without problem.
Script 1 get's 'snapshot cannot be deleted, you don't have access or the snapshot is not present in the database'

If I run script 1 in SQL Studio it works perfectly so I have not spelled anything incorrectly.

Both scrips are running under the same user both in the SSIS engine and in the JOBS engine.

I don't even know where I should start looking for errors for this?? Any suggestions?

------------- Edit: Script added ----------------

```
IF EXISTS(select NULL from sys.databases where name='Citybase_Snapshot')
BEGIN
    DROP DATABASE Citybase_Snapshot;
END

CREATE DATABASE CityBase_Snapshot ON
( NAME = FastighetsBok_Data, FILENAME = 'S:\Snapshots\Citybase_Snapshot.ss' )
AS SNAPSHOT OF Citybase;
```

---------------- Edit: Error message added ----------------------

As far as I know this is a normal error message from SQL server.

```
EXEC proc_..." failed with the following error: "Cannot drop the
database 'Citybase_Snapshot', because it does not exist or you do not
have permission.".
```

Comment: add a check to see ,if there are snapshots present before deleting

Comment: I suggest you post the scripts. A message like that sounds _very_ specific to the code that is running (i.e. I've never heard of that as a native sql error message) so the issue is in the code somewhere

Comment: I am checking if the snapshots are there. Of course. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was more simple than I imagined.

You set an active user on the SSIS script that's running when you create a job in the SQL server for the SSIS job, but that's not the only place you might have a security user on.

You also need to check the connection you actually establish inside the SSIS script to make sure that the user that you use to connect to the database is allowed to drop the snapshot.

Easy as pie (when you know what's wrong).